# How do I add an image upload field to menu content items?

Tags: entities, 8, media

So admins currently have the ability to add custom menu items. I would like to add an image upload field to this form so we can display it in the megamenu alongside the link. How can I add this field?

Comment: Field UI is available to all entities with field ui route set in their annotation. Unfortunately menu links do not have bundles so you are out of luck. But with some custom coding it should not be that hard. Also you can add field programmatically but without UI configuration I think.

Comment: I'm fine with doing it programmatically with a custom module (and no UI-based builder), I just don't know where to start.